# Adding a row for missing column value, with all other column values as NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe with a column with categorical values, e.g. `vegetable = ['carrot', 'eggplant', 'peas', 'tomato', 'zucchini']`. Now, the dataframe also has another column with categorical values (e.g., `location`) and, if we group the dataframe by location, it often happens that a location does not have all the vegetables.

What I would like to do is to group the dataframe by location and, for each location dataframe, add **one row** for each missing vegetable, where all other cells are NaN.

The vegetables should be in alphabetical order, so I would like to add each new row in the right place. What would be the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Kindly share sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: this should work off the bat as in `groupby` we have `observed=False` by default, see the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work off the bat:

```py
import pandas as pd

# specify the rows
rows = [
    {'vegetable': 'carrot', 'location': 'london'},
    {'vegetable': 'carrot', 'location': 'paris'},
    {'vegetable': 'peas', 'location': 'new york'},
    {'vegetable': 'tomato', 'location': 'new york'},
    {'vegetable': 'zucchini', 'location': 'london'}
]

# create df
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

# set as categorical
df['vegetable'] = df['vegetable'].astype('category')
df['location'] = df['location'].astype('category')

# group by and count how many we have
df.groupby(['vegetable', 'location']).size()
```

Output:

```py
vegetable  location
carrot     london      1
           new york    0
           paris       1
peas       london      0
           new york    1
           paris       0
tomato     london      0
           new york    1
           paris       0
zucchini   london      1
           new york    0
           paris       0
dtype: int64
```